# Jenkins with many solutions in one repository

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, build-automation

I am trying to setup Jenkins to automate a build. We have one enormous repository with approximately 100 solution files. To build this repository we have a build program which finds all the solutions and builds in a specified order.

I would like to change that to use Jenkins. Is there a way to setup msbuild and specify a build order for all of these solution files?

p.s. I am trying to avoid creating one mammoth solution file which contains all of the projects.

Answer (score 0):

If in fact all of your projects use ProjectReferences to other VS projects, you should be able to use MSBuild to extract all those references via the ResolveProjectReferences MSBuild task. You can then build an MSBuild script build those dependent projects in order.  There's a pretty good example of this [here](https://maximelabelle.wordpress.com/2011/11/29/building-multiple-projects-in-order-with-msbuild/).  The example given there goes so far as constructing a specialized MSBuild task that builds a dependency graph, which I must say is pretty cool.